# Labels displayed backward in new iOS popup

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios16

after changing the app language from Arabic to English (RTL to LTR) the popup displays the text backward

here's an example:
[Backwards text labels in popup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLYAo.jpg)

and the code for reloading the UI after changing language is:

```
public static func apply(for application: UIApplication) {
    UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = direction
    UIStackView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = direction
    UILabel.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = direction
    UISegmentedControl.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = direction
    UINavigationBar.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = direction
    UISwitch.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = direction
    UIPageControl.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = direction
    UICollectionView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = direction
    UITextField.appearance().textAlignment = (direction == .forceLeftToRight ? .left : .right)
    UITextView.appearance().textAlignment = (direction == .forceLeftToRight ? .left : .right)
}
```

could anyone help?
please let me know if more details are required

Comment: Why do you force direction AND language setting ? This may result in cancel of language setting.

Comment: @PtitXav because changing the language happens in the same app, not outside it, causing me to force changing the direction of each view